# Blackberrry Twitter Integration to tweet photos

Tags: blackberry, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing an application where user can share photos to Facebook and Twitter, for BlackBerry Storm and Torch series phones running OS 5.0.

For Facebook I used the strawberry project. But for Twitter I am not able to find any library which can authorize the user using oauth 1.0 as well as tweet photos.

I tried implementing oauth 1.0 in my code without using any libs but failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/1.7` to download a RIM Twitter api.   Unzip and read index.html for guidance.

**Update**

with working example

http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/Miscellaneous

Comment: It doesn't have a method to upload photos...how shall I go about that? Thanks for your answer