# OAuth Twitter integration with Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, twitter-oauth

I am new to Blackberry App Development..In my app I want to integrate twitter functionality.
I have got the Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access token,Access token Secret.
I dont know from where to start..and what .jar files to add..
Is there any sdk for it,like there is for facebook integration.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4252867/431639

Comment: The two thing do you want to integrate it by REST API or by usin jar there is one jar file named Twitter ApiMe [check this one out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606634/blackberrry-twitter-integration-to-tweet-photos/7607284#7607284)

Comment: Did you try the REST API for twitter ?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter